# What needs to be change when migrationg from jsf 1.x to jsf 2.x , richafaces 3.x to 4.x

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, migration, richfaces

I am new to jsf.
I am working on migration project.
In this I need to migrate from jsf1.2 to 2.1
and richfaces as well..

In general what I need to change?
I have one more requirement that navigation rules must be quoted explicitly in faces-config.xml? 
How to write these rules in faces-config.xml?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: For the first part: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration is probably as good as you get here. For the second part: what do you mean with "quoted"? And why do you want to continue using them in `faces-config`, when one of the major improvements was to get rid of that bloat?

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand that this is a painfull to migrate from `JSF 1.x` to `jsf 2.x` but it is even more painfull to migrate from `Richfaces 3` to `Richfaces 4`.

JSF 1.x to 2.x upgrade can be done independently from Richface upgrade. So I would recommend you first update JSF and check that everything is working and only after that try updating Richfaces. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) question about JSF migration for more info. Or just google it. There is a lot of info about it.

Richfaces 3 to 4 migration is very very painfull because JSF 2 introduced it's own ajax and you will need to change a lot of attributes all overt the project. But the biggest pain is that Richfaces 3 work much more stable than Richfaces 4. Richfaces 4 is very buggy. I can list some bugs that I encountered and some solutions for them.

1. `rich:autocomplete` is very buggy. Not sure if it is fixed already
   but when I tried using it it was not working with Spring in
   composite views(`<ui:include` pages). After I sumbitted bug report
   they seem to do something there but not sure if this works now. I
   didn't check. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11469

   I would advise you to replace this component with simple jQuery UI
   autocomplete component with some spring mvc controller on backend.
2. `rich:tabPanel` is very buggy. Separate tabs do not have action
   attribute any more. This was breaking functionality with initing tab
   contents when the tab was opened with ajax. Immediate attribute also
   not working for tabs. Here is the issue on jboss jira: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11417 workaround is really stupid.

   I just went into source code of richfaces and made it working.
3. Exception handling is very buggy. Seems that exceptions are just
   swallowed in many places in richfaces source on ajax requests so you
   can not handle them the right way.

   I went again into Richfaces code and removed exception swallowing by
   throwing out exceptions.
4. `rich:fileUpload` component can work and can not work for you. You
   can get `request prolog can not be read` exception in some
   cases(This is what I was getting). And This is connected with new
   app server feature of reading multipart request into
   request.getParts(). And Richfaces do not handle such situation and
   error out because inputstream of multipart request is already read
   fully.

   I again went to source code of Richfaces and added catch for
   situation when request.getParts is not empty. I even created an
   issue on Jboss but guys said this works on new Jboss server that's
   why it is not an issue(I use tomcat). https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13061 the issue is close still it is not working on tomcat.
5. A lot of issues on client side. By default multiple forms will not
   work on your pages like they were working in jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3
   because the viewstate id is not updated where and when it needs to
   be.

   To fix this you will need to add additional script. It is described
   in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608595/dynamicly-included-page-form-first-submit-fails) question
6. Also on the client side you should know that if in the response of
   any ajax request you will have some js that will fail everything
   stops working. You can not have js errors inside xhtml. The page
   will freeze completelly. Also it is tricky to have `CDATA` tags on
   the xhtml pages. They can also fail.
7. Richfaces messages work the way that sometimes they show up and
   sometimes not. They are ajax rendered but seems that they can break
   the page. Ajax reposnse can have an update that should update
   messages that is not rendered on the page and when it will not find
   this message in your html it will stop rendering everything that is
   left to update. As a result your links and buttons will not rerender
   anything in some cases.

   Here evaluating `limitRender`attribute helps a lot.

It is a short list. There probably a lot more to be aware of and that you will see after update =)) Richfaces 4 are still buggy.

Comment: Interesting reply, however, even if you say `it's very buggy` for some Richfaces aspects, you totally forget to include references to prove what you're saying.

Comment: References? Anyone can download and check Richfaces and listed issues. I will be very happy if some of them are fixed but I think most of them are still there since Richfaces team is working on 5th version. I hope that it will not have all those issues.

Comment: You talk about some bug report you made to richfaces team but you don't provide a link to it. You say you don't know if it has been already fixed. Isn't it better to provide the reference in order for the OP and future audience to be able to check its status? Just think about people viewing this post one year later. Links are always welcome for this kind of things.

Comment: Speaking as just such a person viewing this post one year later I confirm. Please provide the links requested, and/or your one fixes.